# How to access login user in another service by jwt token in .net

Tags: .net, jwt, .net-7.0

im using .net 7 and implement jwt auhtentication as this

```
private string CreateToken(User user)
{
    var issuer = _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"];
    var audience = _configuration["Jwt:Audience"];
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]!);
    var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
        new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature
    );
    var subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
    {

        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.UserName),
    });
    var expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10);
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
        Issuer = issuer,
        Audience = audience,
        SigningCredentials = signingCredentials
    };
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    var jwtToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    return jwtToken;
}
```

now in another controller i use Authorize attribute ,
now i want to know how can is define the login user in that service and access to its username or id